# different traceId every new http request in spring cloud sleuth

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-sleuth

Recently, I started with spring cloud sleuth to trace the request in the application, and I wrote sample project to test this feature, but when the application is run, the log shows that there are different trace ids for every new http request.

and here is may code:
Config.java

```
package com.cloud;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan()
@EnableAutoConfiguration()
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config {
}
```

Controller.java

```
package com.cloud;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Span;
import org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.SpanAccessor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RestController
public class Controller {

@Autowired
SpanAccessor spanAccessor;
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;
int port = 8080;
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Controller.class);

@RequestMapping("/")
public String hi() throws InterruptedException {
    LOGGER.debug("you called hi");
    debug();
    String s = this.restTemplate
            .getForObject("http://localhost:" + this.port + "/cloud/hi2", String.class);
    return "hi/" + s;
}

@RequestMapping("/hi2")
public String hi2() throws InterruptedException {
    LOGGER.debug("you called hi2");
    debug();
    return "welcome";
}

public void debug(){
    Span span = spanAccessor.getCurrentSpan();
    LOGGER.info("span id is "+span.getSpanId()+" and trace id is "+span.getTraceId());
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
    return new RestTemplate();
}
}
```

and here is log:

```
you called hi: span id is 6716502497271349964 and trace id is 6716502497271349964
you called hi2: span id is -4542377791493777157  and trace id is -4542377791493777157
```

Comment: Which version of sleuth are you using? Can you post a sample somewhere on Github so that we can try to see what's going on?

Comment: I am using 1.0.12 version

Comment: Please post your sample somewhere and provide a link to it

Comment: OK, I will try to post it on Gitub, thanks

Comment: here is the url: https://github.com/IbrahimAl-Zreqat/cloud-sleuth.git
thanks

Comment: I see that you have some really old school way of packaging and setting up the app... Have you tried running this as two separate apps? Maybe your issues are related to calling your own app from the same thread? I'll check it out on Monday cause I'm writing from my mobile

Comment: Ok I will try, but I need to ask you that, can I use spring-cloud-sleuth without @SpringBootApplication annotation? , cause I tried it with spring boot application and all things go smoothly

Comment: I really doubt it. Theoretically you could set everything up yourself but I don't guarantee that it will work. So let's assume that the answer is no

Comment: Ok, I will keep trying to solve the problem, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

i copy/paste your code and it works, but i should mention some diferences:

first and most important, i run it with a main witch of course have and springboot anotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.cloud")
```

second, i delete your Config class, becaouse it doesnt do anything.

third, my spring version is `1.5.1.RELEASE` and the spring cloud version is `Dalston.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`

this are the logs:

```
2017-03-07 10:48:29.716  INFO [traceId,2488a4c8d3f7238a,2488a4c8d3f7238a,false] 4179 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.cloud.Controller                     : span id is 2632535164654658442 and trace id is 2632535164654658442
2017-03-07 10:48:45.162  INFO [traceId,2488a4c8d3f7238a,f5e476485b30fd85,false] 4179 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.cloud.Controller                     : span id is -728327186587517563 and trace id is 2632535164654658442
```

Comment: Yes, this works only if I used @Springbootapplication annotation, I moved to use spring boot with the application worked on and all things are good